# php/mysql join syntax

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have the userids of people who have joined a group in one table but not their names thatlie in another table. So I think I need to do a join.  I'm starting with groupid that describes the grouop.

Table 1, groupmem has groupid and userid for the members.

Table 2, users has userid and username

The users table has every user.  The groupmem only has some who have joined groups.

SQL statement should be something like following but can't get it to work.

```
select users.name
FROM users,groupmem
LEFT JOIN users
on groupmem.userid=users.userid
WHERE groupmem.groupid = 22

22 being some value..
```

Thinking maybe where clause is in wrong place or I am using wrong type of join but or not using on correctly but, in any case, can't get it to work.  Thx for any suggestions:

Comment: Are you sure that the tables names and column names are correct? And what happens when you execute the query?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to get back.. the names of all the people in a group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT u.username
FROM `users` u
LEFT JOIN `groupmem` g
ON u.userid = g.userid
WHERE g.groupid = 22
```

Comment: This did not throw an error message and returned one row according to numrows.  however, I can't access the field username from the row.  Can you recommend a good way to see what is in the results.

Comment: Assuming your variable for each returned row is `$row`, you can simply use `$row['username']` (also assuming the field name in your database is called 'username').

Comment: Used print_r and data was there as name.  I was mistakenly calling $row['users.name'].  Now working.  Thx!

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT users.name
FROM groupmem
LEFT JOIN users ON groupmem.userid = users.userid
WHERE groupmem.groupid = 22
```

Your query seems to be quite right - assuming I guessed your table-structure right.

Comment: the name is in the table users should I substitute users for groupmem?